# Is there a way to invoke a script on git status command?

Tags: git, git-svn, githooks, git-status

I am managing my svn repositories as a git repo through git-svn tool, but there is no way to handle my svn externals. This problem is solved by treating each external as a git-svn repo. This is done using a script and the result is something similar to this:

```
> src/
> -- .git/
> -- Source1.x
> -- Source2.x
> -- .git_external/
> ---- git-svn_external1/
> ------ .git/
> ------ ExternalSource1.x
> ---- git-svn_external2/
> ------ .git/
> ------ AnotherExternalSource1.x
> ------ AnotherExternalSource2.x
```

With the lack of a tool to handle the svn externals, I need to verify each modification through a bash script that is executed manually and it is something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in `ls .` do
  if [ -d $i ] then
    cd $i
    if [ -d .git ] then
      git status .
    fi
  cd ..
  fi
done
```

How can I achieve this automatically while executing the `git status` command on main git-svn repository?

I didn't find any hook related to this situation, so I think that I need to find a workaround to this problem.

Comment: why aren't they submodules?

Comment: @CharlesB: AFAIK, Git submodules and git-svn don't play nicely together. Or at least I could never get them working nicely (although I'll grant that may be my incompetence). If you know of a good way to do it, please do share!

Comment: I don't know :) it was just naive question

Comment: @CharlesB: Dang. For a minute there I thought someone had worked out how to make my life far easier…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general git tries to provide as few hooks as possible, providing them only in situations where you can’t use a script instead. In this situation, just write a script that does your bidding and runs `git status`. Run this script instead of `git status`.

If you call it `git-st` and put it in your PATH, you can call it via `git st`.

Answer (score 3):

A trick I've used a few times is to write a shell wrapper function around `git`.  Assuming you're using Bash (it's similar for other shells), add the following to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
git () {
    if [[ $1 == status ]]
    then
        # User has run git status.
        #
        # Run git status for this folder.  The "command" part means we actually
        # call git, not this function again.
        command git status .

        # And now do the same for every subfolder that contains a .git
        # directory.
        #
        # Use find for the loop so we don't need to worry about people doing
        # silly things like putting spaces in directory names (which we would
        # need to worry about with things like `for i in $(ls)`).  This also
        # makes it easier to recurse into all subdirectories, not just the
        # immediate ones.
        #
        # Note also that find doesn't run inside this shell environment, so we
        # don't need to worry about prepending "command".
        find * -type d -name .git -execdir git status . \;
    else
        # Not git status.  Just run the command as provided.
        command git "$@"
    fi
}
```

Now when you run `git status`, it'll actually run `git status` for the current folder and in any subfolder that contains its own `.git` folder.

Alternatively, you could make this into a new command, either by writing a script as [Chronial](https://stackoverflow.com/users/758345/chronial) [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14613991/220155), or by putting it into a Git alias.  To do the latter, run something like the following command:

```
git config --global alias.full-status '!cd ${GIT_PREFIX:-.}; git status .; find * -type d -name .git -execdir git status . \;'
```

Then you'll be able to run `git full-status` to do the same thing.

(The `cd ${GIT_PREFIX:-.}` part is there to return you to whichever directory you ran the command from; Git aliases by default run from the root of the repository. The rest is as for the function solution above.)

Comment: Note that the command-wrapper trick is more fragile than Git commands are normally. For example, if you were to invoke `git -p status` (perfectly valid, see `man 1 git`), the wrapper above wouldn't work. I consider that a reasonable trade-off, as someone who never uses that style of invocation, but if you do use such arguments, you may want to write a fancier wrapper. Or just hack the Git source code to do what you want in the first place.